# R assign several list elements the same object

Tags: r, list, for-loop, matrix, vectorization

I currently have a loop - well actually a loop in loop, in a simulation model which gets slow with larger numbers of individuals. I've vectorised most of it and made it a heck of a lot faster. But there's a part where I assign multiple elements of a list as the same thing, simplifying a big loop to just the task I want to achieve:

```
new.matrices[[length(new.matrices)+1]]<-old.matrix
```

With each iteration of the loop the line above is called, and the same matrix object is assigned to the next new element of a list.

I'm trying to vectorize this - if possible, or make it faster than a loop or apply statement.

So far I've tried stuff along the lines of:

```
indices <- seq(from = length(new.matrices) + 1, to = length(new.matrices) + reps)
new.matrices[indices] <- old.matrix
```

However this results in the message:

```
Warning message:
In new.effectors[effectorlength] <- matrix :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

It also tries to assign one value of the `old.matrix` to one element of `new.matrices` like so:

```
[[1]]
[1] 8687

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 5486

[[4]]
[1] 0
```

When the desired result is one list element = one whole matrix, a copy of `old.matrix`

Is there a way I can vectorize sticking a matrix in list elements without looping? With loops how it is currently implemented we are talking many thousands of repetitions which slows things down considerably, hence my desire to vectorize this if possible.

Comment: `new.matrices[indices] <- rep(list(old.matrix), length(indices))`

Comment: I bet there's a better way to build a storage object for whatever you're planning to produce.  Are you going to replace each `new.matrices[[k]]`  with some calculated matrix later on?  (It doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to store N copies of the same data) If so, there's no need to pre-create each list entry.  Next question: do you really need a list, or would a 3-rd rank array `allmatrices[i,j,k]` , each layer of which is `oldmatrix` suffice?

Comment: The matrices are 2 in row and n in col, and store the information regarding the genes an individual has. What is happening here, is asexual reproduction via spores. the number of columns is dependent on the number of genes - genes can be duplicated or deleted. Each of `new.matrices` will change after this due to various mutational processes. So for old.matrix[[1]] - say it makes 20 offspring, it gets put in the new.matrix 20 times, before being subject to functions doing mutational processes. This list is also copied to a results list every sim cycle for results purposes.

Comment: You're correct that the layers have to be the same size, but you did say you were putting the same matrix into each layer.  Unless your gene processing is going to change the size of a matrix, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: One of the processes is a deletion or duplication of a gene, this ends up changing the number of columns in individual matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you already solved your problem, anyway, the issue in your code

```
new.matrices[indices] <- old.matrix
```

was caused by trying to replace some objects (the `NULL` elements in your `new.matrices` list) with something different, a `matrix`. So `R` coerces `old.matrix` into a vector and tries to stick each single value to a different list element, (that's why you got this result, and when, say, `reps` is 4 or 8 and `old.matrix` is NOT a 2 x 2 matrix, you also get the `warning`). Doing

```
new.matrices[indices] <- list(old.matrix)
```

will work, and `R` will replicate the single element list `list(old.matrix)` "`reps`" times automatically.